# given a url, can I get which route mapped? similiar to how mvc does it internally?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want a function that, given a URL, returns me the route that matches.

This is exactly what MVC does under the covers, how do they do it?

I have the source, but not sure where to look.

Answer (score 0):

It might match multiple routes, so something like [Phil Haack's Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) might be more useful. The source code is included.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [MvcHandler class](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/23011#266503). Just a note, the `ProcessRequest` uses the RequestContext which is part of `System.Web.Routing`.

You could create your own method by deriving from the correct interfaces. [This article](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2008/08/20/Exploring-SystemWebRouting.aspx) may be of assistance